# How to pass data in url format

Tags: php, url, hyperlink

I'm currently making a table where the email and phone number of clients are clickable. When you click it, it will redirect to another page and execute a filter search on that page.

I wanted to send the data of client email or phone number via the URL, but it seems you can only type in the exact filter search. I wanted when the user clicks a hyperlink it will send the clicked data via URL and execute the filter search.

```
<?php 
    foreach($checked_columns as $key=>$column){
        if ($column){
            if ($key == 'client_email'){?>
              <td>
                  <a href="admin/sales/browse/confirmed-sale?fc=client_email&fv=alif4arsenal97%40gmail.com" class="style1"><?= $sale['client_email']; ?></a>
              </td>
            <?php } elseif  ($key == 'client_phone_number') { ?>
              <td>
                <a href="admin/sales/browse/confirmed-sale?fc=client_phone_number&fv=60192597698" class="style1"><?= $sale['client_phone_number']; ?></a>
              </td>
            <?php } else {?>
                <td><?= $sale[$key]; ?></td>
            <?php } 
        }
    }
?>
```

How can I change the last part of the URL so that it can search it via variable.

Comment: It looks like you're already sending values on the URL.  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: If i get you well, what you wanna achieve is send user's data via url and use that data to filter the database probably for more information or something else. Is that it?

Comment: ohhhh $sale contain data of client_name, client_emails, client_phone_number from table sales. @mickmackusa

Comment: yes but i dont want it to send only that kind of values. I wanted it to send the values in variable $key['client_email'] @David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, currently you are outputting static text:

```
<a href="admin/sales/browse/confirmed-sale?fc=client_phone_number&fv=60192597698" class="style1">
```

And you want to output variables instead.  Consider that you already have an example in your code of how to output the value from a variable:

```
<?= $sale['client_phone_number']; ?>
```

Simply apply that same exact operation for your URL.  The only addition would be to ensure that you [URL-encode the value](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), in case it has non-URL-friendly characters.  Something like this:

```
<a href="admin/sales/browse/confirmed-sale?fc=client_phone_number&fv=<?= urlencode($sale['client_phone_number']); ?>" class="style1">
```

There are a variety of ways you can reorganize your code, perhaps putting the HTML into strings and using `echo` or perhaps applying a PHP templating engine to separate content from markup.  How you organize it is really up to personal preference.  But at its simplest, if you want to output a value then just output the value like you already do.

Comment: Did I not express this advice well enough?

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be refined/refactored to utilize the variable data.

```
foreach ($checked_columns as $key => $column) {
    if ($column) {
        echo "<td>";
            if (in_array($key, ['client_email', 'client_phone_number'])) {
                echo "<a href=\"admin/sales/browse/confirmed-sale?fc={$key}&fv=" , urlencode($sale[$key]) , "\" class=\"style1\">{$sale[$key]}</a>";
            } else {
                echo $sale[$key];
            }
        echo "</td>";
    }
}
```

The `$key` value doesn't look like it needs to be encoded for insertion into the url, but the email seems like a good candidate.

By "staying in" php, I think you will find the snippet easier to read.

Comment: @Alif I can only provide you a confident answer if your question requirements are clear.  `$key['client_email']` won't work because `$key` is a key, not an array containing an element with the key of `client_email`.